# Linear regression line in MATLAB scatter plot

Tags: matlab, regression, least-squares

I am trying to get the residuals for the scatter plot of two variables. I could get the least squares linear regression line using `lsline` function of matlab. However, I want to get the residuals as well. How can I get this in matlab. For that I need to know the parameters `a` and `b` of the linear regression line

```
ax+b
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the function [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/polyfit.html) to obtain the regression parameters. You can then evaluate the fitted values and calculate your residuals accordingly.

Basically `polyfit` performs [least-squares regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) for a specified degree *N* which, in your case will be 1 for straight line regression. The regression parameters are returned by the function and you can use the other function [`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) to get the fitted values from the regression parameters

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [curve fitting toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/), type cftool and press enter and the GUI will appear.

You can use this tool to find a linear polynomial fit for a given data set, as well as many other fits.